# Visual Studio Code Python, determine in launch.json which module is started

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to program in python. Currently I have two runnable modules I want to start with different arguments, when pressing `F5` on each module.

I specified a `launch.json` in the following way to pass arguments to my module:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Simulation.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["-iTestInput"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Every module I start gets passed the argument `-iTestInput`, so everything is fine until then.

Now I wanted to specify two configurations for different modules, so I added a second configuration and wanted to specify the program on which it it should use the config:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Simulation.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["-iSimulation"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ConvertToData.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["-iinput"]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, I want, when I start `Simulation.py` that the argument `-iSimulation` gets passed and when I start `ConvertToData.py`, that `-iinput` gets passed.
But now every time `Simulation.py` starts with the specified argument. I know why this happens (because i specified the name directly and it is the first conifguration). I want that my `launch.json` differentiates between the modules I started.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the names of your launch configs are the same

Try this `launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Simulation",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Simulation.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["-iSimulation"]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: ConvertToData",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ConvertToData.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args":  ["-iinput"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Select the one you want from the combo box on the Debug tab and press <kbd>F5</kbd>

---

**Edit**

Using the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) (v0.5.0) you can use a single launch config using

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "args" : ["${input:chooseArgs}"]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "chooseArgs",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        "Simulation.py": "-iSimulation",
        "ConvertToData.py": "-iinput"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does not work, name doesnt change anything. It will always start the first configuration

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Use the drop down box on the debug tab.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX made an alternative solution